# Using a TSQL Stored Procedure to Convert a String of Uppercase Sentences to Sentence Case

Tags: sql, regex, string, t-sql

I have a database full of rows with Upper Case that I need to convert to Sentence Case using a stored procedure in TSQL.
For Example:
Original String:

```
THIS IS THE FIRST SENTENCE. THIS IS THE SECOND SENTENCE!     THIS IS THE THIRD SENTENCE?  THIS IS THE FOURTH SENTENCE.
```

Converted String:

```
This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence!     This is the third sentence?  This is the fourth sentence.
```

Comment: please google SQL STRING FUNCTIONS

Comment: This doesn't look like initcap job to me @Tab Alleman

Comment: Not saying it is, but it is a job for standard sql string functions.

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this kind of thing would be better handled in a CLR function or in the presentation layer, but here is one way to do it using only tsql:

**Update:**
I've improved my code to detect sentences that begins with a number, so that they will be ignored (i.e if a sentence is `4th sentence`, the `t` after the `4` will still be lowercase.)

```
DECLARE @OriginalString varchar(200) = 'THIS IS THE FIRST SENTENCE. THIS IS THE SECOND SENTENCE!     THIS IS THE THIRD SENTENCE?  4TH SENTENCE.'

DECLARE @TargetString varchar(200),
        @Index int = 2,
        @CurrentChar CHAR(1),
        @FoundBeginingOfSentence bit = 0,
        @BeginingOfSentenceIsANumber bit = 0

SET @TargetString = LEFT(@OriginalString, 1) + LOWER(RIGHT(@OriginalString, LEN(@OriginalString)-1))


WHILE @Index < LEN(@OriginalString)
BEGIN

    SET @CurrentChar = SUBSTRING(@OriginalString, @Index, 1)
    SET @Index = @Index + 1
    IF @CurrentChar IN('.', '!', '?') 
    BEGIN
         WHILE @FoundBeginingOfSentence = 0 AND @Index < LEN(@OriginalString)
         BEGIN
             SET @CurrentChar = SUBSTRING(@OriginalString, @Index, 1)
             IF PATINDEX('[0-9]', @CurrentChar) = 1 
             BEGIN
                 SELECT @FoundBeginingOfSentence = 1,
                        @BeginingOfSentenceIsANumber = 1
             END
             IF @BeginingOfSentenceIsANumber = 0 
             BEGIN
                 IF PATINDEX('[A-Z]', @CurrentChar) = 1 BEGIN
                     SET @FoundBeginingOfSentence = 1
                     SET @TargetString = LEFT(@TargetString, @Index-1) + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@TargetString, @Index, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@TargetString, @Index+1, LEN(@TargetString))
                 END
                 SET @Index = @Index + 1
             END
         END
    END

    SELECT @FoundBeginingOfSentence = 0,
           @BeginingOfSentenceIsANumber = 0 
END
```

[See fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/274c4f/5)

**Note:** You can add whatever sentence delimiter you want to the first `if` statement.

Comment: @Jerms3033: Does my suggestion answer your question? if not, How can I improve it?

Comment: I still think a CLR method would have better performance, but as long as you are happy with my suggestion then I'm happy with it as well :-)